# Return a value Based on EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a existing stored procedure to make a insert of a data. Same SP I would like to return a int value after inserting value.

My question is, how to write the c# code in relation to EF code first?

The return is number 0 or 1. The insert value is 'a' or 'b'

Answer (score 2):

You can execute arbitrary queries and procs using [SqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx)

```
using (var context = new MyContext()) 
{ 
    var input = "a";
    var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("dbo.MyProc @param",    
                                                new SqlParameter("@param", input))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
   // use result
}
```

`@param` is the name of the input param ('a', 'b') to your SPROC and the `<int>` is the type param of the result. You can also bind entities returned in the same way. We've parameterized `input` to avoid Sql Injection issues

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("dbo.MyProc @param",    
                                            new SqlParameter("@param", input))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Edit, re Students**

Unlike a simple integer scalar returned from a SPROC, `Students` sound like first-class entities in your EF Model, and should be created as `DbSets` - this way you can use all the power of `LINQ` translations to Sql.

But yes, if you do have a PROC which already does filtering for you, you can use:

```
var students = context.Database.SqlQuery<Student>("dbo.MyProc @param",    
                                            new SqlParameter("@param", input)))
                      .ToList()
```

This will match all columns matching properties of `Student` and bind them.
Or, if `Student` already is an entity with a `DbSet<>`, there is a `DbSet.SqlQuery` overload:

```
var students = context.Students.SqlQuery("dbo.MyProc @param",    
                                            new SqlParameter("@param", input))) 
                      .ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I need to retrieve lots of data that is "list<Student> SStudent = ....", is it enough to write it or do I need to do more?

Comment: @KLN Did you reply to the wrong thing? Neither your original question or this answer have anything to do with students.

Comment: @KLN Students sound like first-class entities in your EF Model, and should be created as `DbSets` - this way you can use all the power of LINQ translations to Sql. But yes, if you do have a PROC which already does filtering for you, you can replace `result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Student>(...)` or `result = context.Students.SqlQuery(...)` if Student already is an entity with a `DbSet<>`.